# Android native share (ShareActionProvider) bouton with XDK API?

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk, shareactionprovider

Is it possible to use the Android native os share (ShareActionProvider) bouton with XDK API or Cordova?

Comment: I recommend you search for a Cordova plugin that provides access to this feature. If none are available, you'll have to create a Cordova 3.x plugin to get at the feature.

Comment: and how to work with cordova plugin on XDK ? is it possible ?

Comment: It will be possible to use Cordova plugins in the near future. I can't provide a precise date, but we will provide that capability.